# Xcode make view full screen, hide Status bar, Nav Bar and etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a `UIView` and now it is full screen but there are `status bar`, `navigation bar` , `tab bar` etc floating on it, if the user taps the device, I want to hide and show all these bars. My question is maybe I cannot make sure how many bars are there in the window, are there any way to hide or show all the existing bars through the `window` handler, not hide the bar one by one.

Now my code is as below:

```
@interface PdfViewController : UIViewController
{
BOOL _bounceBack;
BOOL _navigatioBarHidden;
BOOL _statusBarHidden;
IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *_doubleTapRecognizer;
IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *_singleTapRecognizer;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
}

- (IBAction)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLOGD_METADATAONLY();
_navigatioBarHidden = (_navigatioBarHidden)? NO: YES;
navigationBar.hidden = _navigatioBarHidden;
_statusBarHidden = (_statusBarHidden)? NO : YES;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
[sender requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_doubleTapRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: with Objective-C

Comment: show your tried code ,

Comment: do you want to hide all bars on `singleTap` click ?

Comment: Yes！And show again when single tap!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You need to implement the prefersStatusBarHidden method in your view controller

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    // If self.statusBarHidden is TRUE, return YES. If FALSE, return NO.
    return (self.statusBarHidden) ? YES : NO;
}
```

And then, in your button click method: Or change with your selector

```
- (void)clickonView:(id)sender
{
    self.statusBarHidden = !self.statusBarHidden
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:self.statusBarHidden animated:YES];

    // Update the status bar
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }];
}
```

Comment: The navigation bar works well but the status bar still shows on the screen when single tap the screen.